# Error while binding a float from form-data request

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, multipartform-data

I've got a following endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test([FromForm] TestRequest request)
    {   
        return Ok();
    }
```

With a following model:

```
    public class TestRequest
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
        public float PriceFloat { get; set; }
        public int PriceInt { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is my request and error:
[image: PostMan Request and response error]

But if I change **22.44** to **22,44** it works good and no errors are returned. Model binding is correct. It seems **there is trouble in that dot**. It quite bothers me because I want to accept cors request from frontend and js floats are serialized with dot, not a comma.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check if system settings for numbers causes this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the number is not binded is your culture settings. Try to to the following in your **Configure** method in **Startup.cs**

```
 app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US")
            });
```

Basically it sets request localization so float numbers with dots will be binded.